# Kubuntu Monitor Out of Range

Tags: display, kubuntu, xorg

My X server seems to be faulty, but I don't know why. I had some problems last week with a new motherboard, but they seemed to be resolved. Today, I updated Kubuntu and restarted, but my Viewsonic VX900 LCD monitor shows the splash screen for several seconds, then displays the message "Out of Range"

I have tried various kernels in Grub, some in recovery mode, most do the same thing. No key combinations bring up a shell prompt like I expect.

The one exception was a very old kernel, that would only mount the file system as read-only, so I can't fix up the xorg.conf file.

Is there anything to be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot using a live Ubuntu CD in VGA mode, you can mount your hard drive from there and modify the xorg.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [these instructions](http://linuxtopia.org/online_books/system_administration_books/ubuntu_starter_guide/ch08.html) to boot into repair mode and [edit your xorg.conf](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=320524)... if your new Kubuntu even has an xorg.conf.

Comment: I have no xorg.conf running dpkg-reconfigure doesn't do anything..?